# Jquery click function trigger load more button

Tags: javascript, jquery

below i have 3 links as an tabs:

```
<li data-tab-id="self" class="tab selected"><a href="activity">Near You</a><span class="unread-count hidden" style="display: none;"></span></li>

<li data-tab-id="friends" class="tab"><a href="#">Following</a><span class="unread-count hidden" style="display: none;"></span></li>

<li data-tab-id="user" class="tab"><a href="#">Your Activity</a><span class="unread-count hidden" style="display: none;"></span></li>
```

when i click the above link Jquery click function are triggered

```
$(".hd-ui-activity li a").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var tabid = $(this).parent().attr('data-tab-id');
    if(tabid == "self"){
            getFunc1(totalRecords);
        } else if(tabid == "friends") {
            getFunc2(totalFriendsRecords);
        } else if(tabid == "user") {
            getFunc3(totalUserRecords);
        }
});
```

When each of the links/tabs are clicked the function eg `getFunc1()` are called which append an html to the following div (Each func have its own div)

```
<li data-section-id="following" data-component-bound="true">
    <ul class="module-list">                            
    <!-- USER ACTIVITY JSON -->
    </ul>
    <a class="ybtn ybtn-primary ybtn-large more-wishlist" href="#" onclick="javascript:getRecentActivityFriends(event)">
    <span data-component-bound="true" class="loading-msg following">See more recent activity</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Only 4 list results are displayed on the div, when user click `see more activity` button, more result are loaded into div. The problems now is when the page load it display correctly 4 results but when i click the link again rather than a button all the data are displayed.Its difficult for me to navigate between tabs. How can i avoid this?

Update:

```
var totalFriendsRecords = '<?=$this->followingTotal?>';
function getRecentActivityFriends(event)
{
    if (event != null){
            disabledEventPreventDefault(event);
        }
        getFriendsActivity(totalFriendsRecords);
}
```

home.js

```
var totalFriendsRecordsView = 0;
function getFriendsActivity(totalFriendsRecords)
{
var activityHtml =  ''
$.ajax({
        url:baseUrl + "activity/feedfollowing",
        data:{'total':totalFriendsRecordsView},
        dataType:"json",
        type:"POST",
        success:function(data){

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
activityHtml = '<p>'+data[i][name]+'</p>';
}
$('#activity-feed li[data-section-id=following] .module-list').append(activityHtml);
if( totalFriendsRecords <=  totalFriendsRecordsView){

                $('.following').text('Nothing beyond here ...');
                $('.following').removeAttr('onclick');
                $('.following').removeAttr('href');
            }

}
});
}
```

Comment: we have no idea what `getRecentActivityFriends(event)` does. Why are you mixing inline javascript and jQuery? Also have no idea what `difficult to navigate tabs` could possibly mean or what `all the data are displayed` means

Comment: Clicking tabs load all the data which i dont want it to be so

Comment: have to show us more code then.

Comment: code that is causing the problem