# Jquery events not binding to newly cloned fields

Tags: jquery

I have a form that allows the user to add more fields.  I do this by cloning the div that they are in.  I do use clone(true) but the problem I am having is that the jquery I use to ensure numeric input doesn't seem to work on the newly cloned fields.  When I type in them they change the values in the top set of fields(the one that was cloned)
This is my clone function

```
$('#more_fields').click(function(){
        if(fields >= 5)
        {
            alert("We're Sorry... You can have a maximum of 6 fieldsets for a freightquote request");
        }
        else
        {
            $('.freight_fields:first').clone(true).hide().insertAfter('.freight_fields:last').slideDown('slow');
                var last = $('.freight_fields:last');
                last.append(new_button.clone(true));
                fields++;
        }
        });
```

And I am using the autonumeric library with the class numbers_only on these fields like this

```
$('.numbers_only').autoNumeric({mDec:0});
```

If any of that was confusing ... when I clone freight_fields (the outer div) which contains field_one and I type in the cloned version of field_one the value in the original is changed and the new one doesn't change.  I'm sure it has something to do with the fact that the true I pass only affects the outer div, but there are a lot of fields in this thing and I don't want to have to clone each of them individually in order to bind them.

Comment: Have you tried [`clone(true, true)`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents-deepWithDataAndEvents), which should copy data and events for the cloned element, and its children too. Also: `this.name` *not* `$(this).attr('name')`; and if you're checking the same property several times, a [`switch () {}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) might be better than `if`/`else if`

Comment: Is this a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333313/jquery-click-function-trigger-load-more-button?rq=1)?

Comment: Just tried it didn't work

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle for this?

Comment: I'll give it a try... never used it before so it might take a bit

Comment: The code is also a mess; readable code is extremely important when posting to SO so it's worth learning how to format it correctly. Indent each block by four spaces (possibly two if you have a lot of levels), remove unnecessary whitespace, etc. Can, alternatively, use http://jsfiddle.net to tidy it up since that has an automated tool, then paste that back here, highlight, and hit CTRL+K to indent as code.

Comment: I took out most of the irrelevant stuff to make it easier to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally unsafe to clone an element that had plugins applied on to inherit the plugins features, unless you know that the plugin was applied to the element in a clone-friendly way.

I strongly advise you to simply clone the element using `clone(false)` and then reapply the plugin on cloned elements.

Comment: Well, something like `var $newEl = $oldEl.clone(false)`; then `$newEl.autoNumeric({ mDec: 0 });`

Comment: Excellent answer. I did this and just ran a loop on all the text inputs to bind this new event.  Thank You